# Converting numbers as Facebook Like Counter

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my current code:

```
    public static string FormatNumber(Int64 num)
    {
        if (num >= 100000)
            return FormatNumber(num / 1000) + "Thousand";
        if (num >= 10000)
        {
            return (num / 1000D).ToString("0.#") + "Thousand";
        }
        return num.ToString("#,0");
    }
```

**Question:**

I want to convert numbers as facebook's like counter.

**Examples:**

190,000 => "190T"

244,555,232 => "190M 500T"

555,123,456,021 = "555B 123M"

Is there a possible way like facebook counter?

Comment: What about 100,020,003? "100M 20T"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to this type of problem:

```
object[][] list = {
                              new object[] {"B", 1000000000}, 
                              new object[] {"M", 1000000}, 
                              new object[] {"T", 1000}
                              };

            long num = 123412456255; // Here should be the number of facebook likes
            string returned_string = "";
            foreach (object[] a in list) {
                if (num / Convert.ToInt64(a[1]) >= 1) {
                    returned_string += Convert.ToInt64(num / Convert.ToInt64(a[1])).ToString() + a[0] + " ";
                    num -= Convert.ToInt64(num / Convert.ToInt64(a[1])) * Convert.ToInt64(a[1]);
                }
            } Console.WriteLine(returned_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic idea of what you want:

```
        const long BILLION = 1000000000;
        const long MILLION = 1000000;
        const long THOUSAND = 1000;

        long a = 1256766123;
        long b;
        string c = string.Empty;

        if (a >= BILLION)
        {
            b = a / BILLION;
            c += b.ToString() + "B";
            a -= (b * BILLION);
        }

        if (a >= MILLION)
        {
            b = a / MILLION;
            if (c != string.Empty)
                c += " ";
            c += b.ToString() + "M";
            a = a - (b * MILLION);
        }

        if (a >= THOUSAND)
        {
            b = a / THOUSAND;
            if (c != string.Empty)
                c += " ";
            c += b.ToString() + "T";
        }
```

And variable c will contain your string.

Comment: The question's example input/outputs limit it to 2 groups, so you'd want "1B 256M" for that number, not "1B 256M 766T". You could do that with a `bool containsBillions = a >= BILLION;` before you modify `a`, then change the last `if` to `if (a >= THOUSAND && !containsBillions)` (but this wouldn't generalize to more groups well).

Comment: I figured the break out would be obvious for users, depending on if they wanted 2 groups or 3 groups I left it out for generallity purposes. I was actually debating that before I posted.